# Submit apple store for review DarkMode UIUserInterfaceStyle key in info.plist

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-darkmode, uiuserinterfacestyle

I have set force lite mode (Opting out of dark mode) by the following code writes in info.plist

UIUserInterfaceStyle
Light

I'm trying to submit IOS application to an apple store for review process. Is there any problem to upload the application?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem for you to upload the application.

From the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app):

> You can also disable support for Dark Mode entirely using an
> Info.plist key.

Set the `UIUserInterfaceStyle` key with a value as `Light` in your app’s `Info.plist` file to disable the dark mode.