# DarkMode UIUserInterfaceStyle key in info.plist for ios 13 below versions

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-darkmode, uiuserinterfacestyle

I have set force lite mode (Opting out of dark mode) by the following code writes in info.plist

UIUserInterfaceStyle
Light

I'm trying to submit IOS application to an apple store for review process. Is there any problem for ios 13 below versions(DarkMode not supported versions). Because UIUserInterfaceStyle not needed for ios 13 below versions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit apple store for review DarkMode UIUserInterfaceStyle key in info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130377/submit-apple-store-for-review-darkmode-uiuserinterfacestyle-key-in-info-plist)

Answer (score 1):

You should be good to submit to the App Store with UIUserInterfaceStyle set to Light in the plist without impacting versions prior to iOS 13.

I have submitted to the App Store with this same plist entry while still needing to support iOS 12 (before dark mode was introduced).